# Is java.util.Date using TimeZone?

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have 2 different computers, each with different TimeZone.

In one computer im printing `System.currentTimeMillis()`, and then prints the following command in both computers:
`System.out.println(new Date(123456));` --> 123456 stands for the number came in the `currentTimeMillis` in computer #1.

The second print (though typed hardcoded) result in different prints, in both computers.
why is that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

How about some pedantic detail.

[java.util.Date](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is timezone-independent.  Says so right in the javadoc.

You want something with respect to a particular timezone?  That's [java.util.Calendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

The tricky part?  When you print this stuff (with [java.text.DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) or a [subclass](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)), that involves a Calendar (which involves a timezone).  See [DateFormat.setTimeZone()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)).

It sure looks (haven't checked the implementation) like java.util.Date.toString() goes through a DateFormat.  So even our (mostly) timezone-independent class gets messed up w/ timezones.

Want to get that timezone stuff out of our pure zoneless Date objects?  There's [Date.toGMTString()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toGMTString()).  Or you can create your own SimpleDateFormatter and use setTimeZone() to control which zone is used yourself.

Comment: java.util.Date is only somewhat timezone-independent. Copy&Paste from Java SDK7 java.util.Date.toString() `TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
        if (zi != null) {
            sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), zi.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
        } else {
            sb.append("GMT");
        }` `date` is a `BaseCalendar` which time zone is set to `TimeZone.getDefaultRef()`

Comment: The key point is that you're talking about the toString() method.  I said I hadn't looked at the toString() implementation, but suspected it involved a Calendar.  You just confirmed that. No disagreement between us.

Comment: The `Date` object works with a `cdate` member (which is a `BaseCalendar`) with a time zone. And then stuff happens which nobody really cares about and `Date` behaves timezone-independent as long as you do not print it. Didn't mean to contradict your answer.

Comment: Note that the Java-doc of the `toString()` Method says _If time zone
information is not available, then <tt>zzz</tt> is empty -
that is, it consists of no characters at all._ **BUT** afaik the code will apply `GMT` when there is no timezone information availalbe (`zi != null` resolves to a false condition).

Answer (score 7):

> why is that?

Because something like "Oct 4th 2009, 14:20" is meaningless without knowing the timezone it refers to - which you can most likely see right now, because that's my time as I write this, and it probably differs by several hours from your time even though it's the same moment in time.

Computer timestamps are usually measured in UTC (basically the timezone of Greenwich, England), and the time zone has to be taken into account when formatting them into something human readable.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but had to vote-up for your explanation/statement of why date without timezone is meaningless.

Comment: @HelterScelter I have to downvote the same thing. It's like saying mass is meaningless without gravity constant. They're both meaningful in their own way.

Answer (score 5):

Because that milliseconds number is the number of milliseconds past 1/1/1970 UTC. If you then translate to a different timezone, the rendered time will be different.

e.g. 123456 may correspond to midday at Greenwich (UTC). But that will be a different time in New York.

To confirm this, use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with a time zone output, and/or change the timezone on the second computer to match the first.

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString().

Yes, it's using timezones. It should also print them out (the three characters before the year).

Answer (score 2):

javadoc explains this well, 
System.currentTimeMillis()
Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger. For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds.