# java.util.Date class using joda

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I want to get a `java.util.Date` class using `joda`.
I need that the date in `Date` class will be format as `yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss` and `GMT/UTC` time.

Thanks.

I will clarify my question: i want that when i print toString of Date i will get the time in format of yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss and as UTC/GMT time.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [JavaDocs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html). I can at least two ways this could be achieved...

Comment: `Date` objects don't **have** a format (or [time zone information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516213/java-util-date-is-using-timezone), for that matter). What you want is probably a `Calendar` (which has time zone information, but still no format).

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime jodaDate = fmt.parseDateTime(utilDate);
```

Comment: I think he is asking to get a `java.util.Date` from a jodaDate

Comment: I will clarify my question: i want that when i print toString of Date i will get the time in format of yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss and as UTC/GMT time.

Answer (score 0):

There is method [DateTime::toDate()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate%28%29) inherited from [AbstractInstant](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html)

You can format `java.util.Date` with
[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

and you can format `DateTime` with
[DateTimeFomratter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Or you can extend `Date` class

```
public class MyDate extends Date
{
   private SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

   public MyDate(Date date)
   {
      super(date.getTime());
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return FORMATTER.format(this);
   }
}
```