# conversion of unix timestamp into date returning wrong time

Tags: java, date

I am generating unix timestamp using 
Date dt=new Date();
long timestamp=dt.getTime()/1000;

It generates accurate timestamp, but while converting same timestamp into date
its returning date which is 5 hours 30 min lesser than current date.

Code is running in India.

Is there any problem related with time zone?
If yes, then could you please help me in setting those appropriate timezone?

Thanx

Comment: what is your code of converting?

Comment: I am converting using following website http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: Q: Have you tried to validate the timestamps against anything else besides that one website?

Comment: Nop. But I m quite sure this website is giving correct output.

Comment: it is a timezone problem,check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516213/java-util-date-is-using-timezone