# Set defaultTimeZone in Spring using FixedLocaleResolver

Tags: java, spring, jodatime

I'm trying to set the default TimeZone in my application.

```
<bean id="localeResolver"class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    <property name="defaultTimeZone" value="America/New_York"/>
</bean>
```

The defaultLocale worked but the defaultTimeZone does not look like it did, because when I instantiate a new Date I get my current TimeZone and not the one I just set.

Comment: The java Date is timezone independent.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516213/java-util-date-is-using-timezone

Comment: How did you conclude that timezone is current timezone ?

Comment: Instantiating a new date uses the default from the java version, it doesn't use the timezone set in/by the `LocaleResolver`. If you want that you need to construct it by different means.

Comment: @ArunM I'm using JodaTime, so when I create a new DateTime is shows my TimeZone (-03:00) instead of NewYork (-05:00).

Comment: @M.Deinum What's the easiest way to do that?